# How to read a continuously updated log file in scala

Tags: scala

I want to read a continuously updated file as (tail -f) in scala, I can't use other tools such as tail because I need to do some extra processing on the records.

So how to keep track of exact file contents every time.

Answer (score 6):

There's an implementation of "tail -f" in Apache commons. http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/input/Tailer.html
With google search, I found another implementation of "tail -f": https://github.com/alaz/tailf/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/osinka/tailf/Tail.scala

Answer (score 4):

You can always call `tail -f` from Scala and then do your extra processing there. Using the `scala.sys.process` API:

```
import scala.sys.process._

def someProcessing(line: String): Unit = {
  // do whatever you want with that line
  print("[just read this line] ")
  println(line)
}

// the file to read
val file = "mylogfile.txt"

// the process to start
val tail = Seq("tail", "-f", file)

// continuously read lines from tail -f
tail.lineStream.foreach(someProcessing) 
// careful: this never returns (unless tail is externally killed)
```

**Edit**: An advantage of this is that there is no polling involved. But in exchange for that this blocks the calling thread in a possibly *non-interruptible* way.